# Add SPF record for multiple systems in different servers

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, spf

I have a domain with a published SPF record (**v=spf1 a mx ip4:xx.xxx.xxx.25 ~all**) for it (e.g: xyz.com)
 also this domain has four subdomains:
`sub1.xyz.com` *xx.xxx.xxx.29* 
`sub2.xyz.com` *xx.xxx.xxx.30* 
`sub3.xyz.com` *xx.xxx.xxx.31* 
`sub4.xyz.com` *xx.xxx.xxx.32* 
and every one of those subs in a different server and different IP, when sending emails from subdomains (let's say for example test@sub1.xyz.com) the SPF check fails, in this situation should I publish individual SPF for every subdomain or include them in the main SPF record? and if I am supposed to include in the main, this must be done in `a` mechanism:

> *"v=spf1 a mx a:sub1.xyz.com a:sub2.xyz.com a:sub3.xyz.com a:sub4.xyz.com ip4:xx.xxx.xxx.25 ~all"*

or
 `include` mechanism:

> *"v=spf1 mx a ip4:xx.xxx.xxx.25 include:sub1.xyz.com include:sub2.xyz.com include:sub3.xyz.com include:sub4.xyz.com ~all"*

or
 `mx` mechanism:

> *"v=spf1 a mx mx:sub1.xyz.com mx:sub2.xyz.com mx:sub3.xyz.com mx:sub4.xyz.com ip4:xx.xxx.xxx.25 ~all
> "*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the email is actually coming from the subdomain, that subdomain needs its own independent SPF record.

Comment: Yes! that true, it turned out that I did not do the right search so that I asked my question, Thanks for the help